# Managing an A record with multiple IPs in Route53 with python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

I have an A record in my route53 with multiple IPs behind it.

Example:
**A record**: dummy.xyz.com points
**IPs** : 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2 and 3.3.3.3
**Routing policy**: Simple

I am using the below code to update the records with single IPs

```
       'Changes': [
        {
            'Action': 'UPSERT',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {
                'Name': subdomain, #recordname
                'Type': 'A',
                'TTL': 300,
                'ResourceRecords': [
                    {
                        'Value': value # ip behind the record
                    },
                ]
```

Is there a way that I can update the multiple IPs behind the record.?

Comment: ResourceRecords is a list that can contain multiple elements.

Comment: @jordanm yes, but do I need to pass different IPs as different values over here like below   'ResourceRecords': [
                    {
                        'Value1': value # ip behind the record
                    },    {
                        'Value21': value # ip behind the record
                    },

Answer (score 1):

It got resolved by this, where 'value' is a list

```
     'Changes': [
        {
            'Action': 'UPSERT',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {
                'Name': subdomain,
                'Type': 'A',
                'TTL': 300,
                'ResourceRecords': [
                    {
                        'Value': value[0]
                    },
                    {
                        'Value': value[1]
                    },
                    {
                        'Value': value[2]
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        ]
```